# Is this question about software recommendations on topic?

Tags: discussion

> **What to use to backup server admin files to Google Drive?**
>
> I'd like to schedule periodic backups of admin files in an Ubuntu
>   server to Google Drive but in a way that the server only uploads the
>   files that have changed without keeping a local backup.
>
> From what I was able to read in a couple of blog posts, Deja-Dup works
>   with Google Drive but I'm not sure if the entire operation could be
>   accomplished from the command line, including Google Drive account set
>   up process. Also, it seems to me that Deja-Dup would create local
>   copies of each file.
>
> In case of restoring a individual file I also would like to just drag
>   and dropping files from Google Drive onto a FTP client, so it would
>   help is the tools used for the backup would upload the raw individual
>   files.